# Overloading "." produces errors

Tags: swift

I can't seem to overload "." and not sure if it's a compiler bug or something I'm doing:

```
@infix func . (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
  return a * b
}
```

I get the errors:

`Expected identifier in function declaration
Braced block of statements is an unused closure`

Comment: You may use Extensions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't overload '.' It's a reserved token for the language. You can however overload the .. and ... operators.

> Operators are made up of one or more of the following characters: /,
>   =, -, +, !, *, %, <, >, &, |, ^, ~, and .. That said, the tokens =, ->, //, /*, */, ., and the unary prefix operator & are reserved. These tokens can’t be overloaded, nor can they be used to define custom
>   operators.

[Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-XID_794)

Comment: Is `()` not part of the grammar in `C++`?

Comment: I don't know C++, but this isn't a discussion on C++. There are some characters you can't overload since they have a specific purpose in the language. Try overloading " or #

Comment: @clcto I fixed my wording to better match the docs. You still can't overload it though

Comment: Ah, so then they have something misleading in the "Advanced Operators" section of the manual: _You can declare and implement your own custom operators in addition to the standard operators provided by Swift. Custom operators can be defined only with the characters / = - + * % < > ! & | ^ . ~_

Answer (score 3):

Swift does allow the definition and overload of custom operators, but it only allows [certain characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-XID_871) to be considered operators.

> Operators are made up of one or more of the following characters: /,
>   =, -, +, !, *, %, <, >, &, |, ^, ~, and .. **That said, the tokens =, ->, //, /*, */, ., and the unary prefix operator & are reserved.** These tokens can’t be overloaded, nor can they be used to define custom
>   operators.

It is therefore illegal to try to overload the period operator, though it can be used as part of another custom operator.

Comment: In fact `.` is not even an operator at all.

Comment: Thanks for that. There was something misleading in the "Advanced Operators" section about the "." overloading. Too bad. Wanted Haskell-like syntax for function composition.

Comment: @BrandonWilliams, you can use the period character in a custom operator. For instance, you can overload the `<.>` operator if you think that it's meaningful.

Comment: @zneak yeah thanks, that was the misleading part in the reference. probably not going to go that route though.